# PixelRation in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to use in PixelRatio in react-native but not sure where I insert my image path.
in react native docs , I don't see any mention about the path of the image when using in pixelRatio

```
    var image = getImage({
  width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
  height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(100),
});
<Image source={image} style={{width: 200, height: 100}} />
```

the source here is the image dimension, but assume i have url, where to write it?
in Image docs of react, I have to write it instead of the source e.g

```
 <Image
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
    />
```

so what the right way to do when I use PixelRatio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Image.source` prop is a plain object descriptor that takes properties `uri`, `width` and `height` (among other image source types, such as embedded assets).

You should be able to construct the image source yourself:

```
const image = {
  uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
  width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
  height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(100)
};

return <Image source={image} />
```

Comment: great, thank you. can you please explain what the size 200, 100 means? and what the function getPixelSizeLayoutSize do? it takes 100 in pixels and convert it to dp relative to the size screen?

Comment: Plain number measurements (e.g. 200) is a DPI measurement. `getPixelSizeForLayoutSize` converts that to actual pixels based on the device screen's pixel density (e.g 1x, 2x or 3x for iOS). You may not need this method at all, just demonstrated how to construct an image source - use case is up to you :)